# ggts can't create new project

Tags: grails, ggts

i'm trying to create new project and everytime get this problem, please help me to figure out the solution

- ggts: ggts-3.6.4.RELEASE
- grails: grails-2.4.4
- jdk: jdk1.8.0_40

[image: ggts error]

Comment: Are you behind a firewall maybe? Looks like Grails may be struggling to pull in some dependencies, also did you try the recommendation from the output?

Comment: @MikeW yes, i did, but i have the same problem. Perhaps, it doesn’t depend on internet connection because i’d copied same folder as now with ggts and libraries to computer before it was upgraded. I had some problems with jdk version and then it was working. And i did same stuff with new computer, but nothing works, i don’t know what the problem is

Comment: @George First try with jdk 1.7. if it works, I'll tell you how to configure for jdk 1.8

Comment: @RahulMahadik doesn’t work

Comment: If you copied the project from one computer to another you'll also need to copy the dependencies from whatever repository you're using, assume maven so your ~/.m2 directory otherwise they'll all have to be pulled in again which can lead to the issue you're seeing

Comment: @MikeW his trying to create new project

Comment: I copied m2 folder from -user/m2 also, no result

Comment: @George Groovy version?

Comment: @RahulMahadik 2.4, also tried 2.5